# How to Display array vales after "x" seconds?

Tags: android, sql

I have a sql query,that retrieve two data rows and i set it to array list.in the other end i take that data and display on the Toast.it's showed first row data and after that showed second row data.it's working fine.but i want to do is when toast display first row data,then it should be pause "x" seconds and display second data.

This is my sql query

```
public ArrayList<Content> getContent(String todayid){
        ArrayList<Content> dataArr=new ArrayList<Content>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();
        String query="select mname from content where schid='"+todayid+"'";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        try {

            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.MEDIA_NAME));          
                Content content=new Content();
                content.setmName(name);
                dataArr.add(content);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return dataArr;
    }
```

This is get sql resul and dispaly

```
 public void getContent(String todayid){

 try {
     ScreenDetailsFunc db=new ScreenDetailsFunc(Screen.this);
     final ArrayList<Content> content=db.getContent(todayid);
     for (final Content data:content){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data.getmName()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
}catch (Exception e){

                    }
    }
```

DB values
[image]

my "todayid" is 16.i add "2.jpg,3.png" to array

Comment: use a handler with postDelayed method

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Handler` with `postDelayed` method

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
ScreenDetailsFunc db=new ScreenDetailsFunc(Screen.this);
final ArrayList<Content> content=db.getContent(todayid);
for (int count = 0; count < content.size(); count++){
       final Content date = content.get(count);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data.getmName()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, 7000 * (count+1);
    }
```

Comment: Same thing happen.first display "2.jpg" after that display "3.png" no wating between them

Comment: please check i have updated. added "7000 * (count+1)"

Comment: Note that this code will only work when executed from the UI thread